# Problem with redirect after log in in react native (expo)

Tags: javascript, firebase, react-native, expo

This is my sign in function :

```
const handleSignIn = () => {
auth
  .signInWithEmailAndPassword(Email, Password)
  .then(userCredentials => {
    const user = userCredentials.user;
    console.log('logged in with:', user.Email);
  })
  .catch(error => alert(error.message))
```

}

and this is my code for what happenes once the user has succesfully logged in:

```
useEffect(() => {
const unsubscribe = auth.onAuthStateChanged(user => {
  if (user) {
   navigation.navigate("START")
  }
})
return unsubscribe
}, [])
```

**Problem:**
now what it shoud do is redirect the user to "start" screen once he enters his log in credentials and they get authenticated from firebase but what this does instead is move back to the start screen without even letting me enter user credentials.
**Note**
*I am using the start screen as a sample screen because I havent worked on home screen yet*

**Below I will paste screenshot of my entire code for better understanding:**

[image: code-1]

[image: code-2]

[image: code-3]